# How to resolve AAR dependency errors when building Android project

Tags: android, android-studio, aar

In the project that I am working on, the code base has about 25 modules shared between a couple of apps, the idea being that the same code could be reused between the apps.

When I build the project, I almost always get the following error:

***Direct local .aar file dependencies are not supported when building an AAR. The resulting AAR would be broken because the classes and Android resources from any local .aar file dependencies would not be packaged in the resulting AAR.***

The module causing that error is usually different.

Oddly, when I *run* the app instead of *building* the project, it works just fine.

I have tried Invalidating Cache and Restarting and re-cloning the repo but it doesn't fix the issue.

Worth mentioning that the problem seems to affect only a few developers.

Any idea why the project runs but doesn't build?

Answer (score 1):

You are using an AAR file in another project. Parent AAP/Module needs to add all dependencies which you have used in your local AAR file.